# ModelState.IsValid with custom view result

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a custom view result that inherits from ViewResult. In my controller I check if `ModelState.IsValid` and then return my custom view. I'm finding that the errors don't seem to be making it to the view. Here's my view result:

```
public class EnrichedViewResult<T> : ViewResult
{
    public EnrichedViewResult(string viewName, T model)
    {   
        this.ViewName = viewName;
        this.ViewData.Model = model;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

And the method I'm calling on my controller:

```
    public EnrichedViewResult<T> EnrichedView<T>(string viewName, T model){
        return new EnrichedViewResult<T>(viewName, model);
    }
```

When I inspect `ControllerContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState` in `ExecuteResult` the ModelState contains errors as I would expect.

#### [Update]

@Andras was spot on. I needed to pass the ViewData from my controller rather than just a model. Easiest way was to grab my base controller's ViewData property (same as what ASP.NET MVC use for the ViewResult helper methods. I changed my custom ViewResult to accept a ViewDataDictionary and my helper methods to below:

```
    public EnrichedViewResult<T> EnrichedView<T>(string viewName, T model){
        if (model != null) {
            ViewData.Model = model;
        }
        return new EnrichedViewResult<T>(viewName, ViewData);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be passing in a `ViewData` object to your result; since that is the container of `ModelState`; not simply the Model.  Typically you then shortcut the creation/passing of the ViewData by using the Controller's ViuewData as a starting point, writing in the model (check out the base controller).

From this code it doesn't there's any way `ModelState` could make it to the view.